# How does Java allocate storage for array of interfaces?

Tags: java

Since interfaces only specify methods and not instance variables, how is storage allotted to something like:

```
Comparable[] aux = new Comparable[20];
```

How much per location storage (i.e. not counting array overhead) will be allocated?

Comment: The array is only allocating enough contiguous memory for the pointers to the objects, it doesn't need to allocate memory for the actual objects itself

Comment: Yup makes sense, if you post this answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is only allocating enough contiguous memory for the pointers to the objects, it doesn't need to allocate memory for the actual objects itself.

We can sometimes forget, Java still uses "pointers" (aka references), it just doesn't provide the same level of access to those pointers that other languages do

Answer (score 1):

Objects are reference types, therefore every Object subtypes (including Comparator and every other interface) are reference types. It means that the size of every array item is the size of an object reference. It doesn't make a difference what kind of object it is.